# Tips for Python build scripts?

Tags: python, error-handling, file-system, makefile

File manipulation code, I've noticed, has two salient properties:

1. It's everywhere, and vitally important to functional software
2. It has *lots* of exceptions.

Please give me some pointers on how I can better improve the usability of this rough draft I wrote yesterday. It assumes some very basic things, and was scraped together after browsing Google as I stumbled through the concepts.

## makeproject.py

```
'''create a simple setup folder for a new project
```

Follows the guide posted at:
http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project

The structure built will match the following:

```
| ProjectName/
|---> LICENSE.txt
    | README.txt
    | setup.py
    | projectname/
    | ---> __init__.py

#For the sake of best practices, __init__.py is left empty.
'''
#! usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, errno

class NewProject(object):
    '''interface for building a directory with a new project in it'''

    def __init__(self, projectname, directory):
        self.project = projectname
        self.base = check_path(directory)
        #project defaults: I don't want them here as class attributes!
        self.SETUP = {

'README.txt' :
'''This is an unmodified README text file.
It contains a list of changes to the program.
It also contains help for dealing with the application.
''',

'LISCENSE.txt' :
'''Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
'''
}

    def newproject(self):
        '''creates a file structure for a new project at `directory`
        '''
        self.name = self.project.replace(' ', '')
        self.path = os.sep.join([self.base, self.name])
    
        sub = self.name.lower()
        subpath = os.sep.join([self.path, sub])

        check_build_path(subpath)
        for filename, content in self.SETUP.items():
            self.buildfile(filename, content, directory=self.path)
        #setup takes arguments, it has its own method
        setup = self.buildsetup()
        self.buildfile('setup.py', setup)
        self.buildfile('__init__.py', directory=subpath)        

    def buildfile(self, name, content="", directory = ""):
        '''opens and creates a new file at `directory` with `contents`'''
        #assumes bad directories have been purified
        if directory == "":
            loc = os.sep.join([self.path, name])
            w = open(loc, 'w')
        else:
            directory = os.sep.join([directory, name])
            w = open(directory, 'w')
        w.write(content)
        w.close()

    def buildsetup(self):
        return '''from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='{0}',
    version='0.1dev',
    packages=['{1}',],
    license=open('LISCENSE.txt').read(),
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
)
'''.format(self.project, self.name.lower())

def check_path(loc):
    '''recursively check if last character in `loc` is like os.sep character.
    If so, remove.'''
    if loc[-1] == os.sep:
        return check_path(loc[:-1])
    return loc
    
def check_build_path(loc):
    d = os.path.normpath(loc)
    if not os.path.exists(d):
        os.makedirs(d)
    else:
        try:
            os.rmdir(d)
        except OSError as ex:
            if ex.errno == errno.ENOTEMPTY:
                print "Directory specified must be new or empty"
                sys.exit(1)
        #if delete was successful, build the directory
        check_build_path(loc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: string 'Project Name', string '/abs/path'"
        sys.exit(1)
    project = NewProject(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    project.newproject()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "operating system code"?

Comment: Code that manages operating system resources: directories, files, permissions, etc. To me, it is one of the lines that separates toy scripts from actual work.

Comment: Unusual definition, one that I don't understand. To me OS code is part of the OS. I don't know what a "toy script" is--if it does useful work, it's not a toy.

Comment: [Toy scripts](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) are for proof of concept or trying out a new branch of study. It doesn't mean it's useless, just not production quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'''create a simple setup folder for a new project
```

The recommendation is to always use """ not ''' for docstrings

```
Follows the guide posted at:
http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project

The structure built will match the following:

| ProjectName/
|---> LICENSE.txt
    | README.txt
    | setup.py
    | projectname/
    | ---> __init__.py

For the sake of best practices, __init__.py is left empty.

'''

#! usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, errno

class NewProject(object):
    '''interface for building a directory with a new project in it'''

    def __init__(self, projectname, directory):
```

The python style guide recommends underscores to separate words
            self.project = projectname

I'd call it self.name not self.project. The name project doesn't convey much useful information.

```
        self.base = check_path(directory)
        #project defaults: I don't want them here as class attributes!
        self.SETUP = {

'README.txt' :
'''This is an unmodified README text file.
It contains a list of changes to the program.
It also contains help for dealing with the application.
''',

'LISCENSE.txt' :
'''Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
'''
}
```

I wouldn't mix large docstrings into my python files. I think that makes it rather hard to read.

```
    def newproject(self):
        '''creates a file structure for a new project at `directory`
        '''
        self.name = self.project.replace(' ', '')
```

I dislike adding object attirbutes not present in the constructor. It makes it harder to know what attributes an object will have

```
        self.path = os.sep.join([self.base, self.name])
```

Use os.path.join for joining paths together. It'll handle a few corner cases that os.sep.join won't.

```
        sub = self.name.lower()
        subpath = os.sep.join([self.path, sub])

        check_build_path(subpath)
        for filename, content in self.SETUP.items():
            self.buildfile(filename, content, directory=self.path)
        #setup takes arguments, it has its own method
        setup = self.buildsetup()
        self.buildfile('setup.py', setup)
        self.buildfile('__init__.py', directory=subpath)
```

I'd probably pass a blank content for `__init__.py` rather then  having it be the default. I figure its rate that you want to have a file like that, so making it default doesn't make sense.

```
    def buildfile(self, name, content="", directory = ""):
        '''opens and creates a new file at `directory` with `contents`'''
        #assumes bad directories have been purified
        if directory == "":
            loc = os.sep.join([self.path, name])
            w = open(loc, 'w')
        else:
            directory = os.sep.join([directory, name])
```

That's not a directory if you've saved the file name over it.
                w = open(directory, 'w')

If you use os.path.join, you won't need to handle these two cases separately.
            w.write(content)
            w.close()

I recommend you use with statement to make sure the file closes correctly

```
    def buildsetup(self):
        return '''from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='{0}',
    version='0.1dev',
    packages=['{1}',],
    license=open('LISCENSE.txt).read(),
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
)
'''.format(self.project, self.name.lower())
```

Again, I don't like putting huge docstrings in the middle of the code. I recommend having a template folder that you copy over to the target. Just do search/replace on filenames and contents for a few keywords like NAME or MODULE.

```
def check_path(loc):
    '''recursively check if last character in `loc` is like os.sep character.
    If so, remove.'''
    if loc[-1] == os.sep:
        return check_path(loc[:-1])
    return loc
```

This is the sorta thing that os.path.join will do for you. I'd also avoid recursion,  because its pretty easy to make this a while loop. Also what happens when loc is "/"

```
def check_build_path(loc):
    d = os.path.normpath(loc)
```

I discourage single letter variable names whenever I can

```
    if not os.path.exists(d):
        os.makedirs(d)
    else:
        try:
            os.rmdir(d)
        except OSError as ex:
            if ex.errno == errno.ENOTEMPTY:
                print "Directory specified must be new or empty"
                sys.exit(1)
```

You should reraise the exception if it was something else.

```
        #if delete was successful, build the directory
        check_build_path(loc)
```

This function would be simpler if done like this:

```
try:
    os.rmdir(d)
except OSError as error:
    if error == ERROR_CODE_FOR_NOT_EXIT:
        pass # OK
    else:
        print "Failed to delete because: ", error
        sys.exit(1)
os.makedirs(d)
```

I think that conveys the logic better

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: string 'Project Name', string '/abs/path'"
        sys.exit(1)
    project = NewProject(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    project.newproject()
```

Comment: There are 3-4 lines of code with formatting issues. Reading would be much better if fixed. I did myself but as formatting doesn't consume characters the fix didnt get accepted as the system requires 6 char changes. I didnt like/want to add text to others answer, but maybe you do.

Comment: @joaquin, I'm not sure what issue you are concerned about. Feel free to add text if you want.